# How can I find how many days has an AWS IAM user been inactive/idle for with boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, boto3, amazon-iam

I would like to enforce a user lockout if that user has not logged in with username and password in aws account.

How can I poll for user activity, when he/she was last active on his/her account?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code prints the time the password was last used.

```
import boto3

iam = boto3.resource('iam')
user = iam.User('john')
print user.password_last_used
```

> 2018-05-02 16:47:28+00:00

Comment: This doesn't actually work. It gives me None if someone's last activity was from today

Answer (score 2):

If you have to check the last use of their access keys and not just their password, you can do the following:

```
import boto3

iam = boto3.resource('iam')
user = iam.User('john')
# use the account creation date if the user has never logged in.
latest = user.password_last_used or user.create_date
for k in user.access_keys.all():
    key_used = iam_client.get_access_key_last_used(AccessKeyId=k.id) 
    key_date = key_used['AccessKeyLastUsed']['LastUsedDate']
    if key_date > latest:
        latest = key_date
print latest
```

However, it may be easier just to use [aws console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/iam-user-unused-credentials-check.html).